# WF with SqlWorkflowPersistenceService Hosted in IIS

Tags: workflow-foundation

I have been working with Windows Workflow (WF) and the SqlWorkflowPersistenceService.  I have successfully created a prototype application using WF and the SqlWorkflowPersistenceService which works fine when running in WebDev service running under my login and integrated secruity.

I then moved my code to a project that is hosted in IIS 5.1.  When loading the SqlWorkflowPersistenceService in this environment the SqlWorkflowPersistenceService tries to use the \ASPNET user to authenticate to the database.  My question is, is there a way to instantiate the WorkflowRuntime in IIS using impersonation?

FYI, Also, I tried switching over the connection string to use a SqlLogin UserID and Password.  The SqlWorkflowPersistenceService fails to login using this.  Doe anyone know if there is an issue using a SQL Login for the SqlWorkflowPersistenceService?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the belated response.  The following works when hosting the workflow service in a webservice running in IIS.  Just add the section to your web config file:

```
<WorkflowRuntime>
    <Services>
        <add type="System.Workflow.Runtime.Hosting.ManualWorkflowSchedulerService,System.Workflow.Runtime,Version=3.0.00000.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
             useActiveTimers="true"/>
        <add type="System.Workflow.Runtime.Hosting.SqlWorkflowPersistenceService,System.Workflow.Runtime,Version=3.0.00000.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
             UnloadOnIdle="true"
             LoadIntervalSeconds="5"
             ConnectionString="Initial Catalog=yourdatabase;Data Source=yourserver;User ID=youruser;Password=yourpassword;"/>
    </Services>
</WorkflowRuntime>
```